# Azure Push Notification Using GCM

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

How to Unregistered one device from particular tag.
I m sending notification with tag.It is working good. but even though i unregister still it is getting notifications.

```
protected async void HandleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent)
        {


            string registrationId = intent.GetStringExtra("registration_id");
            string error = intent.GetStringExtra("error");
            string unregistration = intent.GetStringExtra("unregistered");


//Retriving string From The Memory

            ISharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            string groupname = preferences.GetString ("GroupName","");


            var nMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService (NotificationService);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (registrationId)) {
                NativeRegistration = await Hub.RegisterNativeAsync (registrationId,new[] {groupname.ToString()});

                var notificationNativeRegistration = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.notification, "Your Device Successfully Registered To "+groupname.ToString());
                var pendingIntentNativeRegistration = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);

                notificationNativeRegistration.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "Device ID ", NativeRegistration.RegistrationId, pendingIntentNativeRegistration);
                nMgr.Notify (_messageId, notificationNativeRegistration);
                _messageId++;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (error)) {
                var notification = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.notification, "Gcm Registration Failed.");
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);
                notification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "Gcm Registration Failed", error, pendingIntent);
                nMgr.Notify (_messageId, notification);
                _messageId++;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (unregistration)) {
                if (NativeRegistration != null)
                    await Hub.UnregisterAsync (NativeRegistration);

                var notification = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.notification, "Unregistered successfully.");
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);
                notification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "MyIntentService", "Unregistered successfully.", pendingIntent);
                nMgr.Notify (_messageId, notification);
                _messageId++;
            }
        }
```

I want to know how to unregister a device that previously tagged to?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use service Bus Explorer([Download](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a)) with Microsoft Visual Studio to see all registered devices. You can also un-register devices from registered device list.

Comment: <15:30:19> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Manage claim is required for this operation. TrackingId:bf65054d-036a-467e-b3e2-1a8d34ed8ff7_G7,TimeStamp:1/11/2015 10:00:19 AM

Comment: Thanks a lot jahanzaib aslam But i need to unregister by coding itself. because it must be dynamic right?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in coding. It is a problem in Azure